# Chrome Extension Detect if User Logged in To Any Website in Content Script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Doesn't have to be in the content script. I'm wondering if there's any way to check if say a person is logged into like their bank website as I do not want the content script to do any processing on that for privacy reasons. Is there any easy way to do this without reloading the page. If not what's the easiest way to do this with reloading the page without cookies and comparing htmls?

I need to find if they're logged in on their bank or facebook or anything to disable the script. I do not care if the content script didn't run at all on pages in login areas. I've thought about various ways to detect members area, which all require a reload of the page and come with caveats:

1. Fetch page again using ajax without cookies if possible, to compare with the existing html of the page to see if it's the same. (tricky to send ajax without cookies, deleting and restoring cookies may disrupt user session).. also still requires a reload.
2. Creating an incognito window to fetch again without logging in and compare htmls (but this doesn't work in firefox as incognito is upto the user, it's also a bit annoying)
3. Load into iframe (can't do this either as iframes force load the images too)
4. Check if any logout link exists on page. I was doing this before and it does work most of the time actually but many sites have the logout links hidden in the dom even if it's not logged in. I suppose there may be a way around this if I detect actual style properties. It also doesn't work if the logout link is an icon or something so it's not ideal.

Any other ways to detect if they're in a members area or something?!

I was doing this to refetch it without cookies but it forces images to load as I have to insert it into the Dom to load the url in iframe:

```
function createframe(url) {
    let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
    iframe.sandbox = "allow-scripts";
}
```

Comment: Re 1: both `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest` can make anonymous requests out-of-the box AFAIK, look for examples. The alternative is to use chrome.webRequest to strip the `cookie` and `set-cookie` headers. Re 4: getComputedStyle may help but you'll have to perform it on the entire parent chain to make sure every parent doesn't have `visibility:hidden`, `opacity:0`, `display:none` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I was gonna do webRequest but it's apparently being depreciated for a rule based api.

Comment: ManifestV3 is still in **early** development so a **blocking** webRequest is **not** deprecated and it will work for the next year and it'll work for even much more than that for extensions listed via a Chrome policy.